# Variance of the truncated normal distribution (truncated from below) increases in $\sigma$?

Tags: statistics, derivatives, normal-distribution

I'm wondering whether the variance of the truncated normal distribution increases in $\sigma$ (which seems to hold numerically), where the untruncated normal distribution is $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and the truncated normal distribution is truncated from zero.

I found that there were some discussions on the relationship between the mean of the truncated normal distribution and $\mu$ ([Is the mean of the truncated normal distribution monotone in $\mu$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445164/is-the-mean-of-the-truncated-normal-distribution-monotone-in-mu)), and the relationship between the mean of the truncated normal distribution and $\sigma$ ([Effect of variance on truncated normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937777/effect-of-variance-on-truncated-normal)) but couldn't find any discussion on the relationship between the variance (or standard deviation) of the truncated normal distribution and $\sigma$.

The variance of the truncated normal distribution (truncated from below) is:

$Var(X|X>0)=\sigma^2 \left[1+\frac{\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right) \phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)}{1-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)} -\left( \frac{\phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)}{1-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)} \right)^2\right]$

$\Phi,\phi$ are cdf and pdf of the standard normal distribution.

Is there any proved claim that $Var(X|X>0)$ increases in $\sigma$? Or can we prove it? Any information or insight would greatly help.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward (computer) symbolic integration shows that the variance of the truncated distribution for arbitrary $\mu$ gives:

$$\sigma  \left(-\frac{2 \sigma  e^{-\frac{\mu ^2}{\sigma ^2}}}{\pi 
   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{\mu }{\sqrt{2} \sigma
   }\right)+1\right)^2}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \mu  e^{-\frac{\mu ^2}{2 \sigma
   ^2}}}{\text{erfc}\left(\frac{\mu }{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)-2}+\sigma \right).$$

Here's a graph (for fixed $\mu = 1$):

[image]

Here's the derivative of the variance with respect to $\sigma$:

$$-\frac{4 \sqrt{2} \mu  e^{-\frac{3 \mu ^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{\pi ^{3/2}
   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{\mu }{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)+1\right)^3}-\frac{2
   e^{-\frac{\mu ^2}{\sigma ^2}} \left(3 \mu ^2+2 \sigma ^2\right)}{\pi  \sigma 
   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{\mu }{\sqrt{2} \sigma
   }\right)+1\right)^2}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \mu  e^{-\frac{\mu ^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}
   \left(\mu ^2+\sigma ^2\right)}{\sigma ^2 \left(\text{erfc}\left(\frac{\mu }{\sqrt{2}
   \sigma }\right)-2\right)}+2 \sigma$$

Here's a graph of the variance with respect to $\sigma$ and $\mu$:  always monotonic:

[image]

Comment: You do not give any proofs whether the variance of the truncated normal distribution (truncated from below at zero) increases in $\sigma$... The variance formula has been already given in this question.

Comment: @sndwec It is and old post. But I wonder whether you could prove it or not.